# String resource with font tag not working

Tags: android, html, string

I need help displaying color from the next string resource to the textview

```
<string name="colored">
  <b>Something working perfectly</b>
  <font color="#F38">Something that doesn't work</font>
</string>

<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/colored"
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set it programmatically, like this:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string. colored)));
```

XML:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/yourTextViewId"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

string.xml:

```
<string name="colored"><![CDATA[
  <b>Something working perfectly</b>
  <font color="#F38">Something that doesn't work</font>
]]></string>
```

Answer (score 4):

Font color tag is not working right in string resources in Android. This is because of bug of parsing color in format like "#AARRGGBB". It is using  Integer.parseInt(source, 16) to parse it (in com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt() method) which is accepting only signed int (so you can use range from #7FFFFFFF to #-7FFFFFFF).
Basically Color.parse() using Long.parse() instead and then just making Integer from that.

Also you cannot use your own color resources as references to font colors in strings because it is using System.getResources() method to find color resources. So only "android:color/[colorname]" will work.

In conclusion in font tag you can:

1. use Android system colors as references like `<font color='@android:color/red'>Hello world!</font>`
2. use basic colors like `<font color='red'>Hello world!</font>`
3. use signed integer which is painful because you need to convert negative values to not obvious format like `<font color='#-0000FF00'>Hello world!</font>` where #-0000FF00 is like #FFFF0100
4. use Html.fromHtml() method in runtime to parse HTML-like strings wrapped with CDATA tag like `<![CDATA[<font color='#FFFF0000'>Hello world!</font>]]>`

Comment: One note:
On latest android version <font color='#00FF00'>Hello world!</font> will work correctly with getText().
The problem only on old versions (like Lollipop), so I use <font color='#FF00FF00'>Hello world!</font>.
And it won't change color on old version, but will work on newest. That is ok in my case, cause number of old android sdk devices are going down

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define a color on the resources file and then use it on your layout file?

You can achieve this by defining something like on a colors.xml file (located inside the values folder):

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

and then on your layout (xml)

```
android:textColor="@color/black"
```